# How to diff between 2 files with ignore-matching-lines option with diff command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, diff

I have 2 files where there is a particular string which doesn't match with the other file. I need to ignore that diff using `diff -I RE <file1> <file2>` command.

I found this from `man diff`

```
   -I RE  --ignore-matching-lines=RE
          Ignore changes whose lines all match RE.
```

$cat 1.txt

```
MY_WORD
temp
abc
```

$cat 2.txt

```
YOUR_WORD
temp
abc
```

$diff -I MY_WORD 1.txt 2.txt

```
1c1
< MY_WORD
---
> YOUR_WORD
4d3
<
```

Can someone help me figure out why this doesn't work? `diff` shouldn't have shown any change here.

Comment: Why shouldn't it?  MY_WORD only features in ONE of the files.  `Ignore changes whose lines **all** match RE.`

Comment: What should I do if I need to ignore a particular word in 2 files?

Comment: See my answer ...

Comment: See also [How to diff files ignoring comments (lines starting with #)? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/how-to-diff-files-ignoring-comments-lines-starting-with)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
diff -I ".*_WORD" 1.txt 2.txt
```

Unfortunately diff seems to only understand basic REs, so the prefered

```
diff -I "(MY|YOUR)_WORD" 1.txt 2.txt
```

doesn't work =(

EDIT:
And here what I get with your samples and my invocation (and a non-matching RE as well - there's no leading space):

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt 
MY_WORD
temp
abc
YOUR_WORD
temp
abc
diff -I ".*_WORD" 1.txt 2.txt
diff -I " .*_WORD" 1.txt 2.txt
1c1
< MY_WORD
---
> YOUR_WORD
```

Comment: It still returns `4d3
< ` output

Comment: that then means that one of your ACTUAL files has an empty line that the other doesn't.